# Use a variable within a variable?

Tags: java, variables, loops

I have several fields, each one is like this:

```
field1
field2
field3
...
```

Using a loop with a counter, I want to be able to say fieldx.  Where x is the value of the counter in that loop.  This means if I have 6 entries in my array, fields1 - field6 will be given values.

Is fieldx possible?

Comment: I agree with Mark. Using an array index rather than the field names would be the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html), but in general it is better if you can declare your fields in an array. Instead of:

```
SomeType field1;
SomeType field2;
SomeType field3;
...
SomeType field6;
```

You can do this:

```
SomeType[] fields = new SomeType[6];
```

Then you can loop over the array setting the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i)
{
    fields[i] = yourValues[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Do you know of good code to look at as example?

Comment: Better yet, use some `Collection`. Avoid using arrays when possible.

Comment: While we're introducing arrays to Joe, maybe you can give an example of a foreach and an iterated loop, as well?

Comment: I need to use array in this case.  But thanks Colin!

This is helping a lot.  Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative using a plain ol' array (see Mark's answer), you could use an `Arraylist`.  Declare your fields like so:

```
ArrayList<SomeType> fields = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
```

Then after putting in the fields (most likely using `fields.add(SomeType t)`, you can iterate using:

```
for (Sometype t : fields)
{
    // Do stuff with t
}
```

`ArrayLists` have all the same features of arrays with some additional benefits, like compatibility with generics.

Also note that as of Java 5, you can use for-each loops with arrays!  So, instead of keeping track of indeces and remembering whether you need to call `length` or `size()`, you can use a for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to go through reflection. Have a look at the `java.lang.reflect` package, specifically the `Field` class.