# Java and Its Variables (with many 's'-es) on Swing

Tags: java, dynamic, numbers, jlabel

I'm about to share abit interesting case here about the **java** programming and its **variables**.

First thing I wanted to say is that, we are in these situations:

1. We have **many JLabels** with its **Naming conventions**
   (***jll_txtNormalCnn***).
2. The '**nn**' literally means a coordinate of **(x,y)**. TO be
   precise, it is a digit of (0-9).
3. The screenshot of the [many Variables used here](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/3557/variablenamingnumbers.jpg).

In the screenshot taken; We may see there are 5 x 3 table.
And each column consist of each JLabel placed above it. So it is **mimicing as a board with a text on it.**

My very simple question is not about the Interface, instead; it is about the programming style. **What if....** The **variables are sooOOO many**. Let say there are 100 Variables using that kind of naming conventions. And once we want to **setText**() to each of the variables, we want to **simplify the coding**- instead of typing it one by one.... we wanted to use **for-looping** to reach each of the Variable.... But, I realized it is impossible.

The code below will not work at all;

```
for (int x=00; x<101; x++){
(jll_txtNormalC+x).setText("Something");
}
```

Is there any way around to solve this matter?
I'm not sure whether this is a topic of Dynamic Variable or something, because I never heard about it in Java, except '**Generics**', yes I've heard.

Comment: somewhat related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113040/use-a-variable-within-a-variable-java

Comment: okay, that seems very straight forward...But how to give the position to the interface as the use of the JLabel-case mentioned above? Because of the JLabel positioning onto the board (screenshot -previously) that makes me post this question.... @Thilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if is your requirement(s) strict quadratic and there are [JLabels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) or [JTextFields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) (with its Swing nested/inherits methods and its derivates including [pictures](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)),

2) if you required periodical changes for `Component's` contents

3) if you want to avoiding memory leaks or GPU performace or freeze

4) if you want to simple and easy to get/set data or changes

then put that to the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), by defalut contains `JLabel` in the cell, by defalut contains `JTextField` on CellEdit (Mouse or Keyboard input)

1) then you can pretty to forgot about naming, possitionig and another ZOO, all three areas from MVC and `JTable` would be still consistent

2) you can access to data just from visible/filtered/sorted/removed/rendered `TableView`

3) you can access to all data from `TableModel`

4) plus all `JTable's` features that were added/cames from Java6

5) save lots of time for [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), possitioning on the screen, [Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), access to the concrete `Component`

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's a generics problem.  It's not about dynamic variables, either.  It sounds to me like you're having problems because you've embedded information about the location of the label in a grid inside the variable name.  That's a very bad idea, in my view.

Maybe a better idea is to encapsulate that information inside another object and let it maintain the grid of labels.  That's far better than your variation on Hungarian notation.

Comment: Ya @Duffymo, I realized lately that this is the way of placing the Interface & The Variable problems as you mentioned. Hmmm.... I wonder.... TO encapsulate the inf to another object is quite "okey" I guess... and... DId I mentioned about "Hungarian-Notation"? :D

Answer (score 4):

Simply put: don't use separately named variables for this. Use a collection of some kind, whether it's an array (possibly a `JLabel[][]`), a map or whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when working with grids or matrices you use 2d arrays.

Store your JLabels in a 2d array. You can iterate over them or access labels at (x, y) grid-coordinates using `[x][y]` notation which is easy to read.

```
JLabel[][] labelArray = new JLabel[numRows][numCols];
for(int i = 0 ; i < labelArray.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < labelArray[i].length; j++) {
        labelArray[i][j].setText("Something");        
    }
}
```

Comment: ya that one of course emphasize the earlier answer by @Thilo, but the case is that the panel is using Absolute and many JLabel placed on it... that's why it seems I should "touch-directly" to the JLabel... and still confused.

Answer (score 0):

store the jlabels in an array (5x3 or 10x10).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of UI container component (something like a grid), or maybe just an array.

Answer (score 0):

OTOH idea: create an ArrayList or an array and populate it with Jlabels. Iterate through the collection and call setText for each one.

Answer (score 0):

the prober answer is the several times mentioned 2d array.

but, if your labels have to remain single variables, you can also solve this with reflection:

```
    for (int x=00; x<101; x++){
    Field f = getClass().getDeclaredField("jll_txtNormalC" + x);
    JLabel l = (JLabel)f.get(this);
    l.setText("Something");
}
```

Comment: You *could* use reflection, but not without a good reason... :-)

Comment: waw.... I never touch this "Field" stuff before.... looks gook. I should try first... :D